# How can I make my dash app record the coordinates of a click on the court graph?

Tags: python, html, plotly-dash

I am making a dash app to help me record basketball data. I want to record the coordinates of each shot and eventually bucket them into different zones. My issue lies with getting the coordinates from the click events. Currently the court graph renders no problem, but the click events are never registered even though I believe I have set up the callbacks correctly.

Here is the code I am struggling with:

```
import dash
from dash import html, dcc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_daq as daq
from entry_from import ToggleSwitch, PlayerDropdown, PlayTypeDropdown, ShooterHeader
from court import draw_plotly_court
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()
# Dash app
app = dash.Dash(__name__)

# Layout
app.layout = html.Div(
    children=[
        html.H2("PPP Entry Form"),
        html.Div(draw_plotly_court(fig), id='court-plot'),
        html.Div(id='click-coordinates'),
        ToggleSwitch(),
        #ShooterHeader(),
        PlayerDropdown(),
        PlayTypeDropdown(),
        html.Div(id='shot-switch-result')
    ]
)

# Make or Miss Toggle callback
@app.callback(
    Output("shot-switch-result", "children"),
    [Input("shot-switch", "value")]
)
# Make or Miss Toggle switch logic
def update_shot_result(value):
    if value:
        return "Miss"
    else:
        return "Make"

# Player Dropdown callback
@app.callback(
    Output('player-dropdown-output-container', 'children'),
    Input('player-dropdown', 'value')
)
# Player Dropdown logic
def update_player(value):
    return f'You have selected {value}'

# Play-Type Dropdown callback
@app.callback(
    Output('play-type-dropdown-output-container', 'children'),
    Input('play-type-dropdown', 'value')
)
# Play-Type Dropdown logic
def update_play_type(value):
    return f'You have selected {value}'

# Track click events
@app.callback(
    Output('click-coordinates', 'children'),
    Input('court-graph', 'clickData')
)
def record_coordinates(clickData):
    if clickData is not None:
        x = clickData['points'][0]['x']
        y = clickData['points'][0]['y']
        return f'Shot coordinates: ({x}, {y})'
    else:
        return ''

# Run the app
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

The draw_plotly_court() function returns:

```
return dcc.Graph(
                figure=fig,
                config={'displayModeBar': False},
                style={'width': f'{fig_width}px',
                        'height': f'{fig_height}px'},
                id='court-graph'
            ),
```